# "could not get any sources: no image returned from source WMS" error in mapproxy demo

Tags: mapserver, layers, epsg, mapproxy

I am trying to connect my mapserver to MapProxy. First part of the map file is shown below

```
MAP
FONTSET "fonts.lst"
IMAGETYPE png
MAXSIZE 4000
SIZE 800 800
EXTENT -20000000 -20000000 20000000 20000000
UNITS meters
IMAGECOLOR 153 179 204
WEB
   METADATA
      "ows_enable_request" "*"
      "wms_srs" "EPSG:4326 EPSG:3857 EPSG:2154 EPSG:310642901 EPSG:4171 EPSG:310024802 EPSG:310915814 EPSG:310486805 EPSG:310702807 EPSG:310700806 EPSG:310547809 EPSG:310706808 EPSG:310642810 EPSG:310642801 EPSG:310642812 EPSG:310032811 EPSG:310642813 EPSG:2986"
      "labelcache_map_edge_buffer" "-10"
      "wms_title" "osm france"
   END
   IMAGEPATH "/tmp/ms_tmp/"
   IMAGEURL "/ms_tmp/"
END
DEBUG 1
CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "stderr"
CONFIG "PROJ_LIB" "/home/mwh/osm-demo/basemaps"
PROJECTION
   "init=epsg:3857"
END
LAYER
   TYPE POLYGON
   STATUS ON
   GROUP "default"
   DEBUG 1
   NAME "land0"
   PROCESSING "APPROXIMATION_SCALE=full"
   PROJECTION
       "init=epsg:4326"
   END
   MINSCALEDENOM 332808204
   MAXSCALEDENOM 99999999999
   DATA "data/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp"
   CLASS
       STYLE
           COLOR 242 239 233
       END
   END
END
LAYER
   GROUP "default"
   STATUS ON
   MAXSCALEDENOM 99999999999
   MINSCALEDENOM 332808204
   TYPE LINE
   NAME "borders0"
   PROJECTION
     "init=epsg:4326"
   END
   DATA "data/boundaries.shp"
   CLASS
      STYLE
         WIDTH 0.5
         COLOR "#CDCBC6"
      END
   END
END
```

I followed the [Tutorial](http://mapproxy.org/docs/nightly/tutorial.html) given in MapProxy website to start my  proxy by starting the proxy. The tutorial example works fine. But when I use my own .map
file it shows an error "**could not get any sources: no image returned from source WMS**"

My mapproxy.yaml is shown below

```
services:
  demo:
  wms:
    md:
      title: MapProxy WMS Proxy
      abstract: This is the fantastic MapProxy.
      online_resource: http://mapproxy.org/
      contact:
        person: Your Name Here
        position: Technical Director
        organization: 
        address: Fakestreet 123
        city: Somewhere
        postcode: 12345
        country: Germany
        phone: +49(0)000-000000-0
        fax: +49(0)000-000000-0
        email: info@omniscale.de
      access_constraints:
        This service is intended for private and
        evaluation use only. The data is licensed
        as Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 2.0
        (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/)
      fees: 'None'

sources:
  test_wms:
    type: wms
    req:
      url: http://osm.omniscale.net/proxy/service?
      layers: osm

  mapserver:
    type: wms
    supported_srs: ['epsg:3857', 'epsg:4326']
    req:
      url: http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?
      layers: default
      map: /home/mwh/osm-demo/basemap/osm-google.map
      transparent: true
    coverage:
      bbox: -20000000.0,-20000000.0,20000000.0,20000000.0
      bbox_srs: 'epsg:3857'

layers:
  - name: mapserver
    title: Mapserver Test Layer
    sources: [mapserver]
```

Currently I am stuck in this problem.

Can you help me to find an answer?

Comment: Check request URL's generated by MapProxy.

Comment: Does your Mapserver run OK at the address that you have configured? What do you get with a request
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/mwh/osm-demo/basemap/osm-google.map&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities

Comment: It seems you are on Linux.. right? I had the same issue but it was a file separator problem in the `IMAGE_PATH` and `IMAGE_URL` web params. If you're on Windows, check them out and use double backslashes \\.